# How can I apply module augmentation for a peer dependency?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, type-declaration, tsdx, cra

### My scenario

I am creating a TypeScript package using [TSDX](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/tsdx) (react-storyook template) with a MUI v5 peer dependency.

In the package, I am augmenting the theme in order to customise it, as [documented by MUI](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#custom-variables).

I am then consuming this package by a create-react-app (CRA) using plain JavaScript.

### Problem statement

My module augmentations are only visible to the package while the peer dependency is installed as a development dependency.

The module augmentations are not applied to the peer dependency outside of the package itself (i.e. while it is a peer dependency inside a project depending on both).

How can I have the theme interface module augmentations shared with my CRA project and understood?